# laravel 5.4 duplicates of queries within a nested foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreach, laravel-5.4

In my Laravel 5.4 project i'm trying to fetch some data from a relationship between models Article and Status. The relationship type is OneToMany where Article has one Status and Status has many Articles.

To fetch the wanted data i iterate through a collection of model Article items which is eagerLoaded together with the model/relationship Status with help of a method `whereHas()`. First iteration builds a correct query, but with each other iteration it appends the query generated by the method `whereHas()` [that's my guess].

How can i solve this problem (?) when given ->

Article Model:

```
class Article extends Model
{  
 public function status()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo(ArticleStatus::class,'articleStatus_id');
 }
}
```

Status Model:

```
class ArticleStatus extends Model
{
 public function article()
 {
    return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
 }
}
```

Passing variables through Controller to a view:

```
class RedactionController extends Controller
{
 /**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $articles = Auth::user()->articles();
    $statuses = array_values(ArticleStatus::all()->pluck('status')->toArray());     

    return view('redaction',[
            'articles' => $articles,
            'statuses' => $statuses,
        ]);
}
```

Part of the View where i want to iterate through the data and display them corresponding to article's statuses:

```
<div class="tab-content">
            @foreach($statuses as $count => $status)

                    <div class="card-block tab-pane @if($count==0) active @endif" id="{{$status}}">
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Titulok</th>
                                    <th>Vytvorené</th>
                                    <th>Publikované</th>
                                    <th>Upravené</th>
                                    <th class="text-center">Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                            <p class="mt-5"><b>{{$status}}</b></p>

                            @php 
                                $result = $articles->with('status')->whereHas('status', function ($query) use ($status)
                         {                                                                        
                           $query->where('status','=', $status);
                         })->toSql();   

                                echo $result;           
                            @endphp 
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>

            @endforeach
            </div>
```

The outcome in form of echoed $result variable:

1st Iteration:

```
select * from `articles` where `articles`.`user_id` = ? and `articles`.`user_id` is not null and exists (select * from `article_statuses` where `articles`.`articleStatus_id` = `article_statuses`.`id` and `status` = ?)
```

2nd Iteration:

```
select * from `articles` where `articles`.`user_id` = ? and `articles`.`user_id` is not null and exists (select * from `article_statuses` where `articles`.`articleStatus_id` = `article_statuses`.`id` and `status` = ?) and exists (select * from `article_statuses` where `articles`.`articleStatus_id` = `article_statuses`.`id` and `status` = ?)
```

3rd Iteration:

```
select * from `articles` where `articles`.`user_id` = ? and `articles`.`user_id` is not null and exists (select * from `article_statuses` where `articles`.`articleStatus_id` = `article_statuses`.`id` and `status` = ?) and exists (select * from `article_statuses` where `articles`.`articleStatus_id` = `article_statuses`.`id` and `status` = ?) and exists (select * from `article_statuses` where `articles`.`articleStatus_id` = `article_statuses`.`id` and `status` = ?)
```

So the query builds up each foreach iteration and appends some query at the end of the previous one. If you could give me some advice i'd be thankful.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must take out the query from the foreach and put it in your index function, something like

```
$results = $articles->with('status')->whereHas('status', function ($query) use ($statuses)
                     {                                                                        
                       $query->whereIn('status', $statuses);
                     })->get();
```

This get all Articles which have all Status in `$statuses`, then you can make an structure for your view like

```
$final_results = [];
foreach($results as $article)
{
    if( ! isset($final_results[$article->status->status]))
        $final_results[$article->status->status] = [];

    $final_results[$article->status->status][] = $article;
}
```

With this you have an array with property status of ArticleStatus as keys with their articles, pass the `$final_results` variable to your view.

Then in your view

```
<div class="tab-content">
        @foreach($final_results as $status => $articles)


                <div class="card-block tab-pane @if($count==0) active @endif" id="{{$status}}">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Titulok</th>
                                <th>Vytvorené</th>
                                <th>Publikované</th>
                                <th>Upravené</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        <p class="mt-5"><b>{{$status}}</b></p>
                         @foreach($articles as $article)
                       // Here your code to show Article properties
                         @endforeach
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

        @endforeach
        </div>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your solution, it works fine. Just for the records, the $count variable had to be removed since it isnt declared amd replaced by, for example $loop->index (laravel's variable) ..